# I want that when I click on the add button, the value of the form will be shown in the table below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have given below two screenshots for you to understanding.

First screenshot show to value in form before the click ad Button

[image]

The second Screen Show the value in the table after clicking on Add Button

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help pages about [ask] in order to make sure you provide the right information to get a good answer.

Comment: Please also take the time to read the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's so much information missing for your question. You'd have to provide at least your HTML code and preferably what you have tried yet.

To give you a rough idea of what to do, I'll give you a hint - I will edit my answer if you provide more information, but this should be enough:

```
$('#id-of-button').click(function() {
    // get data from input fields
    var val_product_service = $('#id-of-productservice-dropdown').val();
    var val_description     = $('#id-of-description-input').value();
    var val_uom             = $('#id-of-uom-dropdown').val();
    var val_qty             = $('#id-of-qty-input').value();
    var val_purchase_rate   = $('#id-of-purchaserate-input').value();
    var val_discount        = $('#id-of-discount-input').value();
    var val_tax             = $('#id-of-tax-dropdown').val();

    // create new empty row string
    var new_row = ''

    // append values to new row string
    new_row += '<tr>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_product_service;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_description;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_uom;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_qty;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_purchase_rate;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_discount;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '    <td>';
    new_row +=          val_tax;
    new_row += '    </td>';
    new_row += '</tr>';

    // append new row string to table
    $('#id-of-table').append(new_row);
});
```

As this is just basic HTML, this won't add the edit/delete functionality you asked for. I'd suggest looking up tutorials for that, since the solution would - in my opinion - be too much for stackoverflow. Create some code on your own, then come back if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks, N. M. After a little editing this code work for me.